# .NET MAUI mobile app: Force on-screen keyboard display

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI mobile app, there's support for external NFC readers. When connected, the external NFC reader acts like an external keyboard, typing the recognized data into the focused visual element (e.g. editable entry).

The problem is that when the external NFC reader is connected, the on-screen keyboard is no longer displayed when I tap on an editable field. Apparently, the device decides that I already have a "keyboard" connected and there's no need for an on-screen keyboard anymore.

Is there a way to force the on-screen keyboard to be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the android, you can use the [InputMethodManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager) in the Entry's focused event to make the soft keyboard show. Such as；

```
    private void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager inputManager = (Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager)(Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity).GetSystemService(Android.App.Application.InputMethodService);
        inputManager.ShowSoftInput((sender as Entry).Handler.PlatformView as AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatEditText, Android.Views.InputMethods.ShowFlags.Forced);
        //inputManager.ToggleSoftInput(Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager.ShowForced, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
        // the ToggleSoftInput method was deprecated in API level 31, but it still works
#endif
    }
```

But there is no api for the ios can force the soft keyboard show. User needs to changed the input settings in the device system setting by themself.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not work, when external NFC reader is connected. OnScreen keyboard does not appear.

Comment: Did you try the `inputManager.ToggleSoftInput` method? @Rafael